# Why does mongoose think my object is a string?

Tags: express, mongoose

Ok, here's my model:

```
var Releases = new Schema({
  status: String,
  title: String,
  type: String,
  url: String,
  text: String,
  tracks: Number,
  length: String,
  links: [{ url: String, title: String }],
  images: [{ small: String, big: String, full: String }],
  music: {
    musician: String,
    album: String,
    albumTrack: Number,
    duration: Number,
    releaseDate: Date,
    song: String,
    songDisc: Number,
    songTrack: Number
  },
  twitter: {
    card: String,
    title: String,
    site: String
  },
  og: {
    title: String,
    type: String,
    url: String,
    siteName: String
  }
});
```

And when the user makes a post request I want to save it to the database, here's the making of a new instance:

```
var releases = new Releases({
  status: req.body.status,
  title: req.body.title,
  type: req.body.type,
  url: req.body.url,
  text: req.body.text,
  tracks: req.body.tracks,
  length: req.body.length,
  links: [],
  images: [],
  music: {
    musician: req.body.music.musician,
    album: req.body.music.album,
    albumTrack: req.body.music.albumTrack,
    duration: req.body.music.duration,
    releaseDate: req.body.music.releaseDate,
    song: req.body.music.song,
    songDisc: req.body.music.songDisc,
    songTrack: req.body.music.songTrack
  },
  twitter: {
    card: req.body.twitter.card,
    title: req.body.twitter.title,
    site: req.body.twitter.site
  }
  og: {
    title: req.body.og.title,
    type: req.body.og.type,
    url: req.body.og.url,
    siteName: req.body.og.siteName
  },
})

//push links
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.links.length; i++) {
  releases.links.push({ url: req.body.links[i].url, title: req.body.links[i].title })
}

//push images
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.images.length; i++) {
  releases.images.push({ small: req.body.images[i].small, big: req.body.images[i].big, full: req.body.images[i].full })
}
```

It all works fine, except for the "og" object, when I console log the instance the og object won't show up at all.

I investigated the matter further and realized that the object is considered a string. Or at least that's what I think.

Here's what it looks like if I console log the model:

```
'twitter.title':
  SchemaString {
    enumValues: [],
    regExp: null,
    path: 'twitter.title',
    instance: 'String',
    validators: [],
    setters: [],
    getters: [],
    options: [Object],
    _index: null },
 'twitter.site':
  SchemaString {
    enumValues: [],
    regExp: null,
    path: 'twitter.site',
    instance: 'String',
    validators: [],
    setters: [],
    getters: [],
    options: [Object],
    _index: null },
 og:
  SchemaString {
    enumValues: [],
    regExp: null,
    path: 'og',
    instance: 'String',
    validators: [],
    setters: [],
    getters: [],
    options: [Object],
    _index: null },
```

To me it looks like the og object is considered a string, but the two other objects are treated like objects.

Did I do something wrong? 
Any other feedback is of course appreciated, I'm kind of new to all this.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks! Can I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: No, I'll just mark your question as a duplicate to make it clear.